# Launching a WinForms application programmatically from a WPF application with Administrator permissions

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, vb.net, user-permissions

Hi I'm trying to launch a WinForms Application exe programmatically with administrative rights from a WPF application.

The code in the WPF application being used to launch the WinForms application is as follows :

```
    With procStartInfo
    .UseShellExecute = True
    '.FileName = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\" + "myTestProgram.exe - Shortcut.lnk"
    .FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\myTestProgram.exe"
    .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    .Verb = "runas" 'add this to prompt for elevation
End With

Me._myTestProgram_Process = Process.Start(procStartInfo)
```

I have tried altering the manifest file of the WPF application :
[image]

but that had no effect, The WinForms application still crashes when it tries to execute a part of its program that requires the premissions.

The only way I have managed to launch the WinForms Application is by Using a shorctcut which has administrative privileges, the reference for this shortcut is commented out in the code snippet above.

I'd prefer to launch using the actual program .exe if possible.

Does anyone know what might be preventing the application gaining full administrative privileges when launched programmatically using the code above?

Comment: "highestAvailable" is not good enough to get elevation, you need requireAdministrator.  If you don't see the UAC consent prompt then it isn't going to work.  It is a lot more sensible to alter the manifest of the Winforms app since that is the one that needs to run elevated.  And be sure that you can actually diagnose an unhandled exception, you never want to have to ask a "it doesn't work" question at SO.

Comment: I'd already tried using "requireAdministrator" in the manifest file of the WPF application with no effect. I'll alter the manifest file of the Winforms App as you suggested instead, thanks.